# MongoDB locked after 49 findOne/save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very weird issue with MongoDB, after exactly 49 findOne() and save() my collections is totally locked and I can't do any more query even if I restart my app.

app.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('127.0.0.1:27017/locked-db-test1');

var Product = require('./models/product.js');

var crawlArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8'));

var count = 0;
async.eachSeries(crawlArray, function(crawl, callback) {
    if (crawl.productId !== undefined) {
        var product = new Product();
        product.idProduct = crawl.productId;
        console.log('BEFORE FIND: ' + product.idProduct);
        Product.findOne({idProduct: product.idProduct}, function(err, productBSON) {
            console.log('FIND');
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                count++;
                callback();
            }
            else if (productBSON === null) {
                 console.log('NEW PRODUCT: ' + product.idProduct);
                 product.save(function(err) {
                    console.log('SAVED PRODUCT: ' + product.idProduct);
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                    count++;
                    console.log(crawlArray.length + ' ' + count);
                    callback();
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log(productBSON);
                count++;
                callback();
            }
       });
    }
    else {
        count++;
       callback();
    }
}, function(err) {
    console.log('*** END ***');
});
```

./models/product.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:              {type: String},
    url:                {type: String},
    description:        {type: String},
    images:             {type: [String]},
    size:               {type: [String]},
    dominantColor:      {type: [Number]},
    availability:       {type: Boolean},
    lastCrawlTimeUTC:   {type: Number},
    category:           {type: String},
    price:              {type: Number},
    regularPrice:       {type: Number},
    designer:           {type: String},
    merchant:           {type: String},
    offer:              {type: Number},
    idProduct:          {type: String},
    idMerchant:         {type: String},
    isPresent:          {type: Boolean}
});


productSchema.methods.init = function(crawl) {

};

productSchema.methods.setMerchantInfo = function(crawl, crawlname) {

};

productSchema.methods.setImages = function(crawl) {

};

productSchema.methods.setDominantColor = function(dominantColor) {

};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

data.json:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttwxq0ez0ovqxxt/data.json?dl=0

You're going to need this command to delete the collection:

```
mongo locked-db-test1 --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

**** UPDATE ****

If I remove all the methods or half or the properties of productSchema, it's working fine. Why is it changing something?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your opening new connections to the server for each query whem you should be reusing/closing them after your done.

Comment: How can I fix that? Thanks